# Mongoid: How to return the count of documents matching specific criteria?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I need to return a list of counts (all records, all records matching a certain criteria). I know how to do this using MySQL (`SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE ...`) but I'm not familiar with how to do this using Mongo and Mongoid. How can I fetch these counts in the most efficient way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [Mongoid documentation](http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/finders.html#count):

**Model.count**

Returns the number of documents in the database. If you want to specify conditions use `where`

```
# Get the count of documents.
Person.count
# Get the count of documents given the provided conditions.
Person.where(title: "Sir").count
```

From [MongoDB documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Count):

```
db.mycollection.count( {active:true}
```

Comment: I must have looked right past that in the documentation. =/ Also, +1 for showing the raw Mongo equivalent. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using MongoID you can set the criteria in many ways: http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html

Assume Thing is a Ruby class including Mongoid::Document

As an example you can use the where function and you can then get the number of documents matching, by calling the 'count' finder function.:

```
Thing.where(foo: "bar").count
```